# Join for missing records

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

For the following data sets (super simplified):

table 1

```
ext_id, actions
z1,     100
z2,     100
x1,     200
x2,     200
```

table 2

```
tid, aid, eid, aum
1,   a,   z1,  100
1,   b,   z2,  100
1,   c,   z3,  100
2,   d,   x1,  200
2,   e,   x2,  200
2,   f,   x3,  200
```

I join them like this:

```
create table #temp as
select a.*, tid, aid, aum
from #t a
join #t2 b 
on a.ext_id=b.eid
```

This gives table `#temp` with all records from `#t2` that match with `#t1`, and maps the additional fields it has.

I would like to now match `#temp` with `#t2` (separate query), and get all data for the rest of the `aid`'s, that join based on `tid`:

ie. output should be:

```
ext_id, actions, tid, aid, aum
(null), (null),  1,   c,   100
(null), (null),  2,   f,   200
```

Thank you

Comment: `select a.*, tid, aid, aum
from #t a
RIGHT join #t2 b 
on a.ext_id=b.eid`

Comment: @lad2025 thank you but can you suggest based on joining `#temp` with `#t2` based on `tid`, and get data for the `aid`'s that dont exist in `#temp` but exist in `#t2`?

Comment: show a proper and realistic data sample and the expected  ,.. result  .. change the term of the question is not fair  .. both the comment and the answer provided are  valid answer  without if  .. or others  .

Comment: Fair enough ill accept the provided answer (cant for another 30 minutes) and create a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an outer join.  I would do this as:

```
select a.*, tid, aid, aum
from @t2 b left join
     #t a
    on a.ext_id = b.eid
where a.ext_id is null;
```

Comment: what if ext_id=eid is actually a combination of 5 different types of joins based on first name, last name, email, address, phone number (I just simplied it here). What I am really looking for is join `#temp` with `#t2` on `tid`, and give data for all `aid`'s that are not in `#temp`. `#temp` has both `tid` and `aid`, as it `#t2`

Comment: @user8834780 . . . Then you would have a different question.  This answer addresses the question you did ask.  A new question should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: you are correct, I already asked it and ended up answering myself :)